# Why does std::sort() change the sorted vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, std

here is the problem:

In my first class i have a vector, a double variable and I overload the comparison operators. Here is the relevant code:

```
class City
{
    double distance;
    std::vector<int> coordinates;

    bool operator<(const City& city) const
    {   
        return this->distance < city.distance;
    } 

    // same for the greater-than operator but changing "<" to ">"
};
```

In another class I have a vector of cities, which I have to sort every time a condition is met. For that I have a struct defined as follows:

EDIT: (reference instead of value)

```
struct CitySortHelper {
    bool operator() (const City &x, const City &y) const { return x < y; } 
} city_sort;
```

Now the problem part, when I sort the vector new City objects appear, and I can't explain why:

EDIT:

```
// this prints all current objects in the vector
for (int i = 0; i < totalCities; i++) {
    std::cout << cities->at(i) << std::endl;
}

// after the following line I get new City objects in the 
// vector, that weren't there before the sort. The new objects
// always have distance = 0 and random values in the coordinates
std::sort(cities->begin(), cities->end(), city_sort);

// using the sort with no predicate also gives the same faulty results
std::sort(cities->begin(), cities->end());
```

EDIT: (the copy constructor and assignment operator)

```
City(const City &city)
{
    this->distance = city.distance;
    this->coordinates = city.coordinates;
}

City& operator= (const City &city)
{
    this->distance = city.distance;
    this->coordinates = city.coordinates;

    return *this;
}
```

The weird part is that this only happens if I sort the City objects in ascending order, i.e. if I change the comparator operator in the `CitySortHelper` from "<" to ">" everything works fine.

Any ideas why this happens ?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specialized copy constructor for your City class?

Comment: Why do you need a custom predicate at all if you can just use `std::sort(cities->begin(), cities->end())` and `std::sort(cities->begin(), cities->end(), std::greater<City>)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I also tried without the predicate. In the normal case i.e. `std::sort(cities->begin(), cities->end())` where the less-operator is used, I still get those new objects. Whereas using `std::greater`no problems.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  You'll need to provide a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: you say that you can use std::greater, but I don't see any City::operator>().  On all of the STL impls that I've looked at (ie gcc and that's it) std::greater() just forwards to operator>.  If you have defined City::operator>, then it might be helpful to post that.

Comment: Also, try making your City::operator<() into friend operator<(const City& a, const City& b) instead of a member function.  Total stab in the dark, which is why I didn't post as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`CitySortHelper` needs to take parameters by const reference, not by value. Another thing to keep in mind is that sort uses assignment operator for the `City`; check that your assignment operator is working correctly. Taking care of these two issues should fix the problem.

Comment: I've changed the `CitySortHelper` and checked the assignment operator and the copy constructor. The problem persists. It works for descending but fails for ascending order.

Comment: @iska Could you please update the question to reflect the changes that you have made?

Comment: Here you go. Right now I am sticking with ordering in descending order then reversing the vector :(

Comment: @iska Are you certain that `totalCities` equals `cities->size()`? I just copied your code into a CPP file, and it sorted OK in ascending order.

Comment: Yes, in fact it was among the first things I checked before asking here.

Comment: @iska Could you post your `<<` operator for the `City`? That's the other thing I changed (see [here](http://pastebin.com/bnqk4v4k) for what I ran).

Comment: thanks for trying to help. I'll just give up for now and go to bed. Tomorrow will give it another go. I'll up-vote your answer for all the time I've cost you :)

Comment: @iska That's OK, you didn't have to :) Have fun coding, and good luck figuring out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sort helper to have

```
bool operator() ( const City& x , const City& y) const
```

And also check that City copy constructor and assignment operator do the proper thing

Comment: I've changed the `CitySortHelper` and checked the assignment operator and the copy constructor. The problem persists. It works for descending but fails for ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `std::sort()` if you want to preserve order, you should use `std::stable_sort()`. `stable_sort` guarantees elements maintain their relative order, `sort` doesn't.

Also, it doesn't seem like `sort` is your problem here. It seems there are City objects getting pushed into the vector somewhere, and you aren't noticing them because you're checking on a variable for size instead of the vector's iterators. Try printing like this instead and tell us what comes out:

```
for (std::vector <City> ::iterator it = cities->begin(); it != cities->end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```